# Datomic: Case insensitive query

Tags: clojure, datomic

I am new to Datomic and I am trying to understand how I would go about doing a query that is case insensitive.

For Example:

```
[:find (pull ?u [:user/email])
     :where [?u :user/email "user1@example.net"]]
```

Returns:

```
{:user/email "user1@example.net"}
```

I would like this query to return the same value for an email specified as "USER1@example.net" but Datomic is doing a case sensitive comparison on email as seen here.

```
[:find (pull ?u [:user/email])
     :where [?u :user/email "USER1@example.net"]]
```

Returns:

```
Nothing
```

Any suggestions on the best way to form the query so it does a case sensitive comparison?

Answer (score 5):

To perform a case insensitive query I formed the query using the Clojure `re-find` function to perform a case insensitive regular expression match against the passed email as follows:

```
  [:find (pull ?u [:user/email])
  :where
  [?u :user/email ?email]
  [(re-find #"(?i)USER1@example.net" ?email)]
  ] db)
```

This now returns:

```
   {:user/email "user1@example.net"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just convert query string and database item to lowercase.

```
   (defn case-insensitive-get-email
      [email]
      (d/q '[:find ?lowercaseEmail .
             :in $ ?email
             :where
             [?e :user/email ?originalEmail]
             [(.toLowerCase ^String ?originalEmail) ?lowercaseEmail]
             [(= ?lowercaseEmail ?email)]]
      db (.toLowerCase email)
           )
      )
```

Then

`(case-insensitive-get-email "USER1@example.net")`

will
return

```
"user1@example.net"
```